# After apparently successful git push, the file are not on the target

Tags: git

I am setting up git between two AWS instances (call them A and B). I can pull from A fine and see changes in those files on B.

If I create a new file on B and commit it, when I push from B to A, all seems to go well (I get the git message about writing objects...done) but I don't see the files on the A machine. On the A machine, git status says that those files have been deleted.

How come I never see the pushed files and why does git think they were deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See question [Why won't I see changes in the remote repo after "git push"?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F) in "Unexpected behaviour" section in GitFaq page on Git Wiki.

Comment: From the link: "A quick rule of thumb is to never push into a repository that has a work tree attached to it, until you know what you are doing."

Answer (score 6):

Roll your working directory forward on A. A push is like a fetch done backwards, not like a pull done backwards. It doesn't affect the working directory.

```
git checkout $YOUR_BRANCH
```

Do that on machine A after pushing from B.

Answer (score -1):

If it was apparently successful then it would be apparent that there was success. However, it seems like you apparently are having issues.

Comment: push is opposite to fetch, and does not update working directory. That is the problem that changes are 'not seen'